# NodeJs NPM shipping-fedex throwing error authetication failed

Tags: xml, node.js, authentication, npm, fedex

I am using `shipping-fedex npm`. It's working fine with sandbox mode.

Shipping Rate request in production also working fine. But when I am giving ship request then it is throwing authentication failed error.

What can be making this error?

We have used **Nodejs as server side & NPM as shipping-fedex**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we moved to production then we need to certification process from WIS team

Ref Link :https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/process.html?tab=tab3

Default service will be  standard service & it is not providing shipping.

For enable shipping you need to activate **Advanced Services with Label Certification**. To do this you need to request to fedex support to activate this process.

After activation, they will send email that, they approved your certification.

Once above process done, you can give ship request.